# Error Enumeration yielded no results for SqlDataReader

Tags: c#, sql, compiler-errors, ado.net, sqldatareader

> Error `Enumeration` yielded no results For `SqlDataReader`
>
> System Info:::
>
> to Microsoft Visual Studio Enterprise 2015 Version 14.0.25123.0 D14REL
>   Microsoft .NET Framework Version 4.7.03062
>
> Installed Version: Enterprise SQL Server Data Tools   14.0.50616.0
>   Microsoft SQL Server Data Tools

```
string connString =
        "Data Source=.;" +
        "Initial Catalog=library;" +
        "User id=book;" +
        "Password=sa;";
       // conn.Open();
        using (SqlConnection c = new SqlConnection(connString))
        {
            sql = @"SELECT * FROM kala";
            // conn.Close();

            SqlCommand cn = new SqlCommand(sql, c);

             c.Open();

            SqlDataReader dr = cn.ExecuteReader();

            if (dr.HasRows)
            {
                while (dr.Read())
                {
                    //empID = dr.GetInt32(0);
                    //empCode = dr.GetString(1);
                    //empFirstName = dr.GetString(2);
                    //empLastName = dr.GetString(3);
                    //locationCode = dr.GetString(4);
                    //locationDescr = dr.GetString(5);

                    //display retrieved record
                    //Console.WriteLine("{0},{1},{2},{3},{4},{5}", empID.ToString(), empCode, empFirstName, empLastName, locationCode, locationDescr);
                }
            }
        }
```

Comment: First check your ConnectionString. Also check the `c.Open()` is opening SQL connection or not.

Comment: Your tag says `compiler-errors`. I can say with certainty this is a runtime error, not a compiler one.

Comment: Which line of code throws the exception?

Comment: @RahulNikate is checked,Connection OK :(